# Is chmod 757 safe?

Tags: security, chmod

As i am on a shared host , i want to add a image hosting script and it seems that with 755 it doesnt allow me to upload images, so i changed the folder to 757 , is it safe to chmod to 757?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a word, no.  In two words, "hell. no!"

Let's interpret 757:  that would be

- owner: read write execute
- groups that have permissions on the file: read - execute
- the rest of the freaking world: read write **execute**

now, consider someone malicious uploading a short shell script:

```
 #!/bin/sh --
 rm -rf /
```

**Update**

Aha, the "folder".  Okay, here's the deal: if you don't have the execute bit set on a directory, that blocks searching the directory.  The reason the host is asking you to do the world=RWX is that they aren't running the web server as you, so they're taking the simple and dumb route to fix it.

There are two possibilities here:

- they have some scheme in place to make sure that the permission of uploaded *files* in that directory can't have the execute bit set
- they don't and haven't gotten burned yet

[Here's an article](http://www.mysql-apache-php.com/fileupload-security.htm) on what better methods are.

On the assumption that your hosts aren't fools, see what happens with 775.

Comment: so what can i do for such a script to make it work in a shared host?is it my shared host that doesnt allow me 755 to upload images or others cant aswell?

Comment: You can contact your host and ask why their system is busted.

Comment: @fxuser: it depends on the host. If everyone you're sharing with has their web server running as the same user, there's no safe way at all to have a directory writable by the web server that other users couldn't exploit.

Comment: so the solution was to change the PHP Support setting: from Apache Module to FastCGI application... and now everything seems to work as intended