# Folder Permissions Error from WordPress on Localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, file-permissions, chmod

I am no longer able to auto-update my local WordPress install. The problem started after [fixing dropbox file permission errors](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/quickly-fix-dropbox-permissions-errors-in-os-x/). Now when I try to install I get this message:

```
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-3.9.2-partial-1.zip…

Unpacking the update…

Could not create directory.

Installation Failed
```

`sudo chmod -R 755 myblog` gives same error.

`sudo chmod -R 757 myblog` works, but [757 is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651180/is-chmod-757-safe).

Why is it failing and is there a way to get it to work with 755?